# Why there is no way to derive Applicative Functors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, generics, applicative, deriving, derivingvia

In Haskell, you can derive `Functor`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` automatically using `deriving`. There is no way to derive `Applicative`, though. Considering there is one obvious way to define an `Applicative` instance (which would amount to a zipped application), isn't there any way to enable `deriving Applicative`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, this is not obvious at all. Compare the following `Applicative` instances:

1. `[]`
2. `ZipList`
3. [`Data.Sequence.Seq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html), whose [`Applicative` instance declaration](https://github.com/haskell/containers/blob/7615e4238cd7968d4abc27539974afe9b0b5024b/Data/Sequence.hs#L275) runs to several hundred lines.
4. `IO`
5. `(->) r`
6. Parsers in `parsec`, `attoparsec`, `regex-applicative`.
7. [Proxy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/src/Pipes-Internal.html#Proxy) in the `pipes` package.

There very little uniformity here, and most of the instances are non-obvious.

---

As [David Young](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476735/david-young) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787252/why-there-is-no-way-to-derive-applicative-functors-in-haskell/29787376#comment47704265_29787376), the `[]` and `ZipList` instances "are both, ultimately, two different, equally valid `Applicative` instances for the list type."

Comment: Also, `[]` and `ZipList` are both, ultimately, two different, equally valid `Applicative` instances for the list type.

Comment: So maybe we need a Zippable class? That is, for things like deriving `Additive` (which, on turn, seems to have one obvious definition) without having to declare an [Applicative instance](http://lpaste.net/131202). (Maybe I should ask another question?)

Comment: My bad. [Additive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.18.0.1/docs/Linear-Vector.html) is a class from Linear package which implements additive groups of vector spaces. For example, `[1,2,3] ^+^ [1,1,1] == [2,3,4]`. It has a generic implementation, but it depends on Applicative which isn't derivable, so you can't derive `Additive` for, say, `data Triple a = Triple a a a` regardless of having an obvious derivation. Edit: hm whoever asked what Additive is deleted it. I'm not talking alone lol.

Comment: @Viclib Ha, that was me sorry. I just remembered that it was in `linear` and I was thinking no one saw it yet. Anyway, I think the major issue is that some types can have multiple equally valid `Applicative` instances, similar to `Monoid`.

Comment: Yep, but not multiple equally valid `Additive` instances, right? So it seems like there is something wrong here...

Answer (score 8):

Now that [`DerivingVia`](https://www.kosmikus.org/DerivingVia/deriving-via-paper.pdf) has been released (GHC-8.6 or newer) it is actually possible to derive `Applicative` with the help of `DeriveGeneric` for any *deterministic* data type! That is to say, any data type with exactly one variant:

```hs
data Foo x = Foo x | Fe  -- This is non-deterministic and can't derive Applicative
data Bar x = Bar x x (Bar x) -- This is deterministic and can derive Applicative
data Baz x = Baz (Either Int x) [x] -- This is also ok, since [] and Either Int
                                    -- are both Applicative
data Void x -- This is not ok, since pure would be impossible to define.
```

To derive `Applicative`, we first need to define a wrapper for deriving via generics:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module Generically1 where

import GHC.Generics

newtype Generically1 f x = Generically1 { generically1 :: f x }

fromg1 :: Generic1 f => Generically1 f a -> Rep1 f a
fromg1 = from1 . generically1

tog1 :: Generic1 f => Rep1 f x -> Generically1 f x
tog1 = Generically1 . to1

instance (Functor f, Generic1 f, Functor (Rep1 f)) 
       => Functor (Generically1 f) where
  fmap f (Generically1 x) = Generically1 $ fmap f x

instance (Functor f, Generic1 f, Applicative (Rep1 f)) 
       => Applicative (Generically1 f) where
  pure = tog1 . pure
  f <*> x = tog1 $ fromg1 f <*> fromg1 x

instance (Functor f, Generic1 f, Monad (Rep1 f)) => Monad (Generically1 f) where
  return = pure
  m >>= f = tog1 $ fromg1 m >>= fromg1 . f
```

and to use it we first derive `Generic1` for our data type and then derive `Applicative` via our new `Generically1` wrapper:

```
data Foo x = Foo x (Int -> x) (Foo x)
  deriving (Functor, Generic1)
  deriving (Applicative, Monad) via Generically1 Foo

data Bar x = Bar x (IO x)
  deriving (Functor, Generic1)
  deriving (Applicative, Monad) via Generically1 Bar

data Baz f x = Baz (f x) (f x)
  deriving (Show, Functor, Generic1)
  deriving (Applicative, Monad) via Generically1 (Baz f)
```

As you can see, we did not only derive `Applicative` for our data types but could also derive `Monad`.

---

The reason that this works is that there are instances for `Applicative` and `Monad` for the `Generic1` representations of these data types. See for example the [Product type (:*:)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t::-42-:). There is however no instance of `Applicative` for the [Sum type (:+:)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t::-43-:), which is why we can't derive it for non-deterministic types.

You can see the `Generic1` representation of a data type by writing `:kind! Rep1 Foo` in GHCi. Here are simplified versions (excluding meta-data) of the representations for the types above:

```
type family Simplify x where
  Simplify (M1 i c f) = Simplify f
  Simplify (f :+: g) = Simplify f :+: Simplify g
  Simplify (f :*: g) = Simplify f :*: Simplify g
  Simplify x = x

λ> :kind! Simplify (Rep1 Foo)
Simplify (Rep1 Foo) :: * -> *
= Par1 :*: (Rec1 ((->) Int) :*: Rec1 Foo)

λ> :kind! Simplify (Rep1 Bar)
Simplify (Rep1 Bar) :: * -> *
= Par1 :*: Rec1 IO

λ> :kind! forall f. Simplify (Rep1 (Baz f))
forall f. Simplify (Rep1 (Baz f)) :: k -> *
= forall (f :: k -> *). Rec1 f :*: Rec1 f
```

---

Edit: The `Generically1` wrapper is also available here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.7.0.0/docs/Generic-Data.html#t:Generically1

Comment: Here's a few more examples of using `DerivingVia` with `Generics`: https://github.com/Icelandjack/deriving-via/blob/master/examples/Generics.hs

Comment: [`Generically1`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/17147) is being added to `GHC.Generics`