# Scala 3. Defining extension for class + all subclasses

Tags: scala, types, monads, scala-3, subtyping

Learning Scala 3.

below code

```
// monad defined for Option
  given Monad3[Option] with {
    def flatMap_[A, B](ma: Option[A])(fm: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = ???

    def return_[A](a: A): Option[A] = ???
  }

  extension[M[_] : Monad3, A] (cont: M[A])(using monad: Monad3[M]) {
    def flatMap_[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B] = monad.flatMap_(cont)(f)
  }

  extension[M[_] : Monad3, A] (contCont: M[M[A]])(using monad: Monad3[M]) {
    def join_(): M[A] = monad.join(contCont)
  }

  // test

  val flattenedOpt = Option(Option("hello!")).join_()
  println(flattenedOpt)
```

works for me.

**Question**:
how do I modify signature of the helper extension for join so the below code with subtypes also works? Question is about Scala 3 syntax, not about monads, libraries, etc...

```
val flattenedOpt = Some(Some("hello!")).join_()
```

Is it smth with type bounds?

thanks

Comment: No you can't AFAIK, the best you can do is provide smart constructors that automatically upcast the subtypes; e.g. using **cats**: `"hello!".some.some.flatten`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question is about Scala 3 syntax, not about monads, libraries, etc...

Well, the thing is that the question is exactly about monads, not Scala 3 syntax etc. You can define separate instances of `Monad` for `Option` and `Some`

```
given Monad3[Option] with
  def flatMap_[A, B](ma: Option[A])(fm: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = ma match
    case Some(a) => fm(a)
    case None => None
  def return_[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)

given Monad3[Some] with
  def flatMap_[A, B](ma: Some[A])(fm: A => Some[B]): Some[B] = fm(ma.value)
  def return_[A](a: A): Some[A] = Some(a)
```

But generally you can't derive an instance for subtype or supertype from an instance for a type. That's because `Monad` can be only invariant with respect to `M[_]`, not covariant (`Monad[+M[_]]`) or contravariant (`Monad[-M[_]]`).

[Calling generic function with Functor using subclass (cats/scalaz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181109/calling-generic-function-with-functor-using-subclass-cats-scalaz)

[Why can find `Functor` instance for Tree but not for Branch or Leaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545028/why-can-find-functor-instance-for-tree-but-not-for-branch-or-leaf)

[Cats instances for Some and None et al](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749544/cats-instances-for-some-and-none-et-al)

[Can I get the compiler to realize there is an Applicative for the superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75299469/can-i-get-the-compiler-to-realize-there-is-an-applicative-for-the-superclass)

Also for some [ADTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) / [GADTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type) (case classes, sealed-trait hierarchies) parametrized with a type constructor, generic derivation is possible for the type classes `Functor`, `Traversable`, `Foldable` but not for `Monad` or `Applicative` because there is no standard way to flatten arbitrary data types.

[Why there is no way to derive Applicative Functors in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787252/why-there-is-no-way-to-derive-applicative-functors-in-haskell)

[Why is there no `-XDeriveApplicative` extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861231/why-is-there-no-xderiveapplicative-extension)

[Haskell - Automatic Monad instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60457433/haskell-automatic-monad-instance)

---

If you're really asking just about Scala 3 syntax for type bounds, it's the same as in Scala 2 i.e. `def foo[A <: B : TC]` (for a type class `TC[A]`), `def foo[A[x] <: B[x] : TC]` (for a type class `TC[A[_]]`).

You shouldn't write `extension[M[_]: Monad3, A](cont: M[A])(using monad: Monad3[M])`. It should be either implicit parameter `extension[M[_], A](cont: M[A])(using monad: Monad3[M])` or context bound `extension[M[_]: Monad3, A](cont: M[A])`.

Comment: thanks for extended format of your answers, it was very interesting to read links you provided